# How to select whole text in cell on click in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables, edit

I need to edit the dataTables jQuery code, so when I click in the editable cell, it will select whole text in the cell. I know its usually done with onclick="this.select()", but jQuery code is very hardly readable for me... Code I have so far (at least I understood this is the code I need to edit):

```
"fnDrawCallback": function () {
        $('#table_dzs tbody tr td:nth-child(7)').editable( './files/save_dzs.php?stavba=<?echo $stavba;?>', {
            "callback": function( sValue, y ) {
                var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
                oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[2] );

            },
            "submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
                return { "id": oTable.fnGetData( this.parentNode )[0], // get the value of first row/column. In my case it is the "id" in database
                "value": oTable.fnGetPosition( this )[7] // Column number
                };

            },
            "height": "14px"
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line after datatable initialization:

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.select = true
```

It's a public dictionary for customization of editable plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Don´t know if I can ask another question right here, but wouldn´t you know how to make that editable cell "visible", so it could be clear it can be edited? Right now it looks like a simple text and nothing visually suggests, that it can be edited...I´d like to make it look like a standard text field.

Comment: There is no such customization option in the plugin. I know how to solve it by changing .js source code, but I think such solution is not good for posting in comment, because too much changes is needed to make it works.

Comment: OK so I will create a new question. EDIT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802239/datatables-changing-the-appearance-of-the-editable-cell