# DataTables: Changing the appearance of the editable cell

Tags: datatables

Can someone help me to make editable cell "visible", so it could be clear it can be edited? Right now it looks like a simple text and nothing visually suggests, that it can be edited...I´d like to make it look like a standard text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/url/",
    "fnDrawCallback": function () {
        $('#example tbody td').editable( 'url', { // simple editable initialization
          "height": "14px",
        }); 

        $('#example tbody tr').each(function() {  
            $.each(this.cells, function(){
                $(this).click()  //by default all td's have bind for click function, so we simulate clicks for every td
            });
        });

        $('#example tbody td input').live('click', function(){
            $(this).select() // to select input
        })
     }
 });
  $.editable.types.defaults.reset = function (){   //this function disables reset input editing after submiting

  }
```

UPDATE:

I made a test sample here http://jsfiddle.net/94BZV/31/

Don't forget to put correct url in init of editable to get correct answer passed back to edit field.

Comment: Thanks, it´s definitely better, but it becomes "textarea" only after clicking into it and then clicking somewhere else...when the page loads, it looks like a plain text and when i submit value in the field by enter, it also becomes "text only" again...

Comment: Did you paste the last 3 lines from my answer code?  They are doing the trick. Just paste it without implementation inside.

Comment: Yes I pasted it exactly according your sample, I checked if it´s correctly placed in my code and it seems so... But it works like I wrote :/ I need to first click into it so it could be displayed like textarea.

Comment: See my updated answer. I made jfiddle sample, I think it would be suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

> are you want this in ASP.net or what? if yes then,if your text is in GridView then you have to set EDITINDEX Value to the rowindex value of the list,as if the EDITINDEX value is -1 then it is static mode then every thing will be displayed in label so you should change it value to Greater Than >-1 Then The Controls will be displayed in TextBoxes So then You can edit the Value in the Controls"

Comment: Sorry, It didn´t come to my mind I should have to specify it like this :) I want it for web app in PHP/JS.